# How to refresh a div in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

I am facing one issue

I am uploading profile picture

It saved to s3 bucket and it returns url

But I am facing one issue

Once the picture updated it need to refresh the page for showing new image

I need to update that div once the picture get updated

Here is my Ajax call

```
$("#profile-pic-upload").change(function () {
    var input_detail = this;
    console.log(input_detail);
    var data = new FormData();
    var file = this.files[0];
    data.append("file", file);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: $("#profile-file-upload").data('action'),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (data['status'] == true) {
                toastr.success(data.msg);
                $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+data.avatar+')');
            }
            else {
                toastr.error(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="avatar-preview">
    {% if user_profile.avatar %}
        <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url('{{user_profile.avatar}}');"></div>
    {% else %}
        <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url('{% static 'assets/img/user-64x.png' %}');"></div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

In the above code I am getting image url from data.avatar

But my issue is it only getting updated only the once

For example if there is no image updated it getting updated

If there is a image in user profile I updated to new one Then it upload to s3 bucket but it will not display in the div. I need to refresh the page for displaying it there

Comment: Not getting what you mean by "_it get updated it will not upload_"?

Comment: If there is a image in user profile 

I updated to new one

Then it upload to s3 bucket but it will not display in the div without refreshing the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your success callback change your:

```
$('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+data.avatar+')');
```

to:

```
var randomId = new Date().getTime();
$('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url(' + data.avatar + '?random=' + randomId + ')');
```

You can use whatever randomId you want to force the image being refreshed, I've chosen to use the current timestamp.

Changing just one parameter like this one forces the web broser to reload an image, javascript... and not use the one in cache.

Comment: It's a new parameter, as one parameter has changed the web browser will not use its cache and this way you force the reload of that resource. It's a trick we usually use

Comment: I'm glad I could help